# Pandas, Multi-index - re-index both index levels with keymap and keep structure

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, jupyter-notebook, multi-index

having a heck of a time getting what I am expecting with pandas multidimensional frames, and specifically when I try to sort them on one column followed by another. I will try to walk through this to best explain what I am after and appreciate the help.

So I have a dataset that I am looking to analyze, and for an example it looks like below in excel:

```
        Data Opportunity Name Geo Map Forecast Category  Total
0   source_1    opportunity_1   geo_1          pipeline    100
1   source_1    opportunity_2   geo_1            upside    200
2   source_1    opportunity_3   geo_1            commit    300
3   source_1    opportunity_4   geo_1               won    400
4   source_1    opportunity_5   geo_1           omitted    500
5   source_2    opportunity_6   geo_2          pipeline    600
6   source_2    opportunity_7   geo_2            upside    700
7   source_2    opportunity_8   geo_2            commit    800
8   source_2    opportunity_9   geo_2               won    900
9   source_2   opportunity_10   geo_2           omitted   1000
10  source_3   opportunity_11   geo_3          pipeline   1100
11  source_3   opportunity_12   geo_3            upside   1200
12  source_3   opportunity_13   geo_3            commit   1300
13  source_3   opportunity_14   geo_3               won   1400
14  source_3   opportunity_15   geo_3           omitted   1500
15  source_4   opportunity_16   geo_4          pipeline   1600
16  source_4   opportunity_17   geo_4            upside   1700
17  source_4   opportunity_18   geo_4            commit   1800
18  source_4   opportunity_19   geo_4               won   1900
19  source_4   opportunity_20   geo_4           omitted   2000
```

I am loading that dataset into pandas by reading it from excel into a dataframe, df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/nick/Downloads/example_data.xlsx')
```

I want to show the data first indexed on the 'Geo Map' field, and then on the 'Forecast Category' field, but I want to have control over the order in which those values are sorted. In order to make sure I can do this, I create a keymap for both of those fields in the two formats I think I could need:

```
regions_array = {'geo_2': 1, 'geo_1': 2, 'geo_4': 3, 'geo_3':4}
regions_list = ['geo_2', 'geo_1', 'geo_4', 'geo_3']
categories_array = {'pipeline': 1, 'upside': 2, 'commit': 3, 'won': 4, 'omitted': 5}
categories_list = ['pipeline', 'upside', 'commit', 'won', 'omitted']
```

When I go to move the data into a pivot table, I am able to achieve the multi-index structure I am after via a pivot with:

```
regional_numbers = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Geo Map', 'Forecast Category'],
columns='Data', values='Total', fill_value=0, aggfunc='sum')
regional_numbers
```

result:

```
Data                       source_1  source_2  source_3  source_4
Geo Map Forecast Category                                        
geo_1   commit                  300         0         0         0
        omitted                 500         0         0         0
        pipeline                100         0         0         0
        upside                  200         0         0         0
        won                     400         0         0         0
geo_2   commit                    0       800         0         0
        omitted                   0      1000         0         0
        pipeline                  0       600         0         0
        upside                    0       700         0         0
        won                       0       900         0         0
geo_3   commit                    0         0      1300         0
        omitted                   0         0      1500         0
        pipeline                  0         0      1100         0
        upside                    0         0      1200         0
        won                       0         0      1400         0
geo_4   commit                    0         0         0      1800
        omitted                   0         0         0      2000
        pipeline                  0         0         0      1600
        upside                    0         0         0      1700
        won                       0         0         0      1900
```

However, now I need to re-order my indices by first the 'Geo Map' and then by the 'Forecast Category'. I have tried to sort_index, reindex, but the problem is once I sort based on the first everything is fine but the second level breaks the frame.

What I would like my result to look like is based on sorting from my keys for first the 'Geo Map' and then 'Forecast Category':

```
Data                       source_1  source_2  source_3  source_4
Geo Map Forecast Category                                        
geo_2   pipeline                  0       600         0         0
        upside                    0       700         0         0
        commit                    0       800         0         0
        won                       0       900         0         0
        omitted                   0      1000         0         0  
geo_1   pipeline                100         0         0         0
        upside                  200         0         0         0
        commit                  300         0         0         0
        won                     400         0         0         0
        omitted                 500         0         0         0
geo_4   pipeline                  0         0         0      1600
        upside                    0         0         0      1700
        commit                    0         0         0      1800
        won                       0         0         0      1900
        omitted                   0         0         0      2000      
geo_3   pipeline                  0         0      1100         0
        upside                    0         0      1200         0
        commit                    0         0      1300         0
        won                       0         0      1400         0
        omitted                   0         0      1500         0
```

### Extra Credit

If I could then add total rows into the equation, that would be the ultimate end state I am looking for. I was trying to add margins=True and margin_name in the pivot arguments but then I needed to sort the Total column in the keys which I ideally want to avoid. End state for the extra credit would be:

```
Data                       source_1  source_2  source_3  source_4
Geo Map Forecast Category                                        
geo_2   pipeline                  0       600         0         0
        upside                    0       700         0         0
        commit                    0       800         0         0
        won                       0       900         0         0
        omitted                   0      1000         0         0
        Total                     0      4000         0         0  

geo_1   ...                     ...       ...       ...       ...
        Total                     X         X         X         X

geo_4   ...                     ...       ...       ...       ...
        Total                     X         X         X         X

geo_3   ...                     ...       ...       ...       ...
        Total                     X         X         X         X

TOTALS                            X         X         X         X
```

It would also be nice to have the totals to the right of all the sources as well on a row level, but having trouble getting that to show correctly.

If the way I am asking for the totals is not possible, I am sure I can figure out totaling the values I want separately but would be nice.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

EDITED to fix my expected output.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match your input.  Note geo_1 has values for source_1, your output shows geo_2 has values for source_1.

Comment: Shouldn't be the columns also reordered?

Comment: @ScottBoston you're right my apologies, I changed the columns names instead of actually reordering them. I will fix that now.

Comment: @AndrejKesely no the columns can stay the same, only the rows within the index should move

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: `categories_array` have keys starting with capital letters, change them to be the same as in your dataframe.

Try:

```py
def add_total(x):
    x = pd.concat(
        [
            x,
            pd.DataFrame(
                {c: [x[c].sum()] for c in x.columns}, index=[("", "Total")]
            ),
        ]
    )
    return x


regional_numbers = regional_numbers.reindex(
    sorted(
        regional_numbers.index,
        key=lambda k: (regions_array[k[0]], categories_array[k[1]]),
    )
)

regional_numbers = (
    regional_numbers.groupby(level=0, as_index=False, sort=False)
    .apply(add_total)
    .droplevel(0)
)

regional_numbers["TOTAL"] = regional_numbers.sum(axis=1)

regional_numbers = pd.concat(
    [
        regional_numbers,
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                c: [regional_numbers.xs("Total", level=1).sum().loc[c]]
                for c in regional_numbers.columns
            },
            index=[("TOTAL", "")],
        ),
    ]
)

print(regional_numbers)
```

Prints:

```
                           source_1  source_2  source_3  source_4  TOTAL
Geo_Map Forecast_Category                                               
geo_2   pipeline                  0       600         0         0    600
        upside                    0       700         0         0    700
        commit                    0       800         0         0    800
        won                       0       900         0         0    900
        omitted                   0      1000         0         0   1000
        Total                     0      4000         0         0   4000
geo_1   pipeline                100         0         0         0    100
        upside                  200         0         0         0    200
        commit                  300         0         0         0    300
        won                     400         0         0         0    400
        omitted                 500         0         0         0    500
        Total                  1500         0         0         0   1500
geo_4   pipeline                  0         0         0      1600   1600
        upside                    0         0         0      1700   1700
        commit                    0         0         0      1800   1800
        won                       0         0         0      1900   1900
        omitted                   0         0         0      2000   2000
        Total                     0         0         0      9000   9000
geo_3   pipeline                  0         0      1100         0   1100
        upside                    0         0      1200         0   1200
        commit                    0         0      1300         0   1300
        won                       0         0      1400         0   1400
        omitted                   0         0      1500         0   1500
        Total                     0         0      6500         0   6500
TOTAL                          1500      4000      6500      9000  21000
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej this is spot on, any chance you can help me to add a TOTAL column to the right of Source 4 that will total up the values from the rows? Same concat function just rows vs columns?

Also changing the keys, good catch. My actual dataset has them capitalized.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but curious how you might approach excluding the Total rows from the calculation in the bottom TOTAL row if that makes sense so the totals are not inflated?

Comment: @NickGardner See my update. Is this what you want?

Comment: Thats a bingo, thanks Andrej!

Answer (score 1):

Try using pd.MultiIndex.from_products then reindex:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([regions_list, categories_list], names=['Geo Map', 'Forecast Category'])
df_out = regional_numbers.reindex(idx)
df_out
```

Output:

```
Data                       source_1  source_2  source_3  source_4
Geo Map Forecast Category                                        
geo_2   pipeline                  0       600         0         0
        upside                    0       700         0         0
        commit                    0       800         0         0
        won                       0       900         0         0
        omitted                   0      1000         0         0
geo_1   pipeline                100         0         0         0
        upside                  200         0         0         0
        commit                  300         0         0         0
        won                     400         0         0         0
        omitted                 500         0         0         0
geo_4   pipeline                  0         0         0      1600
        upside                    0         0         0      1700
        commit                    0         0         0      1800
        won                       0         0         0      1900
        omitted                   0         0         0      2000
geo_3   pipeline                  0         0      1100         0
        upside                    0         0      1200         0
        commit                    0         0      1300         0
        won                       0         0      1400         0
        omitted                   0         0      1500         0
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, tried this but when I run the code it gives me NaN values for all the columns. I see what you are doing here though, building the index first then reindexing by that but it seems like the values are being lost?

Comment: NIck this is due to your list and data values have capitalization differences. Omitted vs omitted.

Comment: Thanks Scott makes sense, I corrected that after the fact thanks again!